# Seagate Backup Plus portable USB HDD beeps and won't mount

Tags: linux, usb, data-recovery, hard-drive-failure, portable-harddrive

About two years ago, I bought me a Seagate "Backup Plus" Portable HDD, 2 TB capacity. Model: SRD00F1. And indeed, I filled it with some content. It's not critical material, but - it's the only copy I have.

A couple of months ago, I noticed I was having trouble reading: The drive would spin down and up, and make a sort of a beeping sound occasionally. Not always and not everywhere, but it would happen.

I hadn't used it since then, but now, when I even connect the drive, I get a spin up, then a pair of consecutive beeps, then a wait and more spinning sounds, then another pair of beeps, and this repeats. Delay between the pairs of beeps is not fixed (taking a different amount of time to fail twice?)

I'm not getting clicks - at least - not that I can discern. On the other hand, this is a slim drive, so I'm not sure what the equivalent of a regular-size drive click would sound like.

Now, of course this means the drive is unsafe for further use. Also, next time I should make sure I have a second copy. But - I want to try and save my data.

My questions are, therefore:

- What's the exact diagnosis? Why is it beeping?
- What, if anything, can I do to gain access to the data (and copy it elsewhere)?

Notes:

- It's a USB-only drive, not something with a separate enclosure. Here's how it looks (except for the size on the box):
  [image]

PS - I should mention my (Linux) desktop does notice the drive as a USB device. Here's some dmesg output:

```
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:56:13 2020] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:00 2020] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:00 2020] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab26, bcdDevice= 1.08
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:00 2020] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:00 2020] usb 1-9: Product: BUP Slim BK
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:00 2020] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: Seagate
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:00 2020] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: NA96GTCY
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:00 2020] scsi host6: uas
kern  :notice: [Fri Jan 17 20:59:00 2020] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  BUP Slim BK      0108 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
kern  :notice: [Fri Jan 17 20:59:00 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:01 2020] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
kern  :err   : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] usb 1-9: stat urb: status -71
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] usb 1-9: USB disconnect, device number 39
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: tag#17 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: tag#17 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
kern  :notice: [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense not available.
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
kern  :notice: [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense not available.
kern  :notice: [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
kern  :notice: [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 0-byte physical blocks
kern  :notice: [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
kern  :debug : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 77 6c 61 6e
kern  :err   : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Asking for cache data failed
kern  :err   : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:19 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:20 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
kern  :notice: [Fri Jan 17 20:59:20 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense not available.
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:20 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
kern  :notice: [Fri Jan 17 20:59:20 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense not available.
kern  :notice: [Fri Jan 17 20:59:21 2020] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
daemon:err   : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:21 2020] udevd[6675]: inotify_add_watch(7, /dev/sdd, 10) failed: No such file or directory
kern  :info  : [Fri Jan 17 20:59:21 2020] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: Looks like it's failing - safest bet is bin it & replace. Run some SMART tests if you can mount the drive over something other than USB [which generally doesn't carry SMART data]

Comment: @Tetsujin: Goes without saying that I'll bin it. I just want to get my data off it.

Comment: It's not a **backup** if it has the only copy of any data. Could you clarify this essential detail in your question; that you're on a rescue mission. The answers will be the same as many others - pick a disk recovery software.

Comment: @Tetsujin: See edit. Also - there seem to be lower-level failures which would prevent recovery software from even running. Or - am I wrong? Please elaborate in an answer.

Comment: @einpoklum - I am not sure an answer is possible.  There already is an existing question with answers that provide possible file recovery software that might work.  At this point if the data is valuable enough you should, stop and do absolutely nothing, except sending it to a professional data recovery service.  They will have the tools and hardware to recovery your data.  Any attempt you make will just make their job harder.

Comment: @Ramhound: 1. At least an answer to the first part of the question should be possible. 2. People with relevant experience could venture a guess which part of the hardware is failing, and consequently, what the prospects are for recovering the data.

Comment: @einpoklum - I have relevant experience, and we don’t actually have enough information, to even speculate.  Best send it to somebody so they can look at the physical drive.

Comment: Remove the hard drive from the enclosure and use a usb to hard drive cable to see if it will mount now, its possible the drive is good but the enclosure has failed.

Comment: @Moab: I'm not using an enclosure separate from the drive; are you suggesting I pry the drive's plastic shell apart? I've attached an image above.

Comment: Some drives have the USB electronics integrated. Removing it from the shell may or may not be possible https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-14cbupb3mE seems like this can tho

Comment: @einpoklum yes remove it from the shell, it may your only chance to recover data, that or send it to a professional.

Comment: @Moab: I remember being told that I am not supposed to expose the disk platters to regular air, and that they should only be exposed in a clean room. Are you certain that there is some additional, cover inside the plastic outer shell, and I won't inadvertantly be damaging the device?

Comment: @einpoklum Inside the external plastic casing is a regular 2.5" SATA drive, which is what moab is referring to.  As to opening an HDD's casing _(not what moab was referring to)_, yes, it must be done within a cleanroom and a platter removal tool must be used to keep the platters aligned, else the data will be unintelligible.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm not aware of any consumer-level external HDD that integrates the USB electronics directly onto the drive's firmware PCB... what drives have you come across that have this, as they'd have to use a firmware PCB that has the USB integrated onto the board itself.

Comment: WD does in my experience.

Comment: @JW0914 All I have ever seen is a proprietary sata connection on the drive itself. But that was years ago.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I would like to see pictures of that, interesting.

Comment: @Moab: You were right. I've written a (very) partial answer based on your comment and my attempts so far.

Comment: Do it all the time, 90% of the time its the usb host adapter that fails, not the drive.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I've opened plenty of WD external drives and never have I found one with anything other than a SATA PCB firmware board, regardless if it was a 2.5" or 3.5".  A model number would definitely help, as I've never come across what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer - just one phase of what you should do with your drive. It is due to @Moab's knowledgeable advice!

#### 1. Problem "reduction" -> external USB device to plain HDD

In fact, your external drive is just a simple a slim 2.5" form-factor SATA disk drive, attached to a SATA-to-USB interface circuit, enclosed in some plastic. And this is likely true for many (most?) external HDDs which look like a thin wallet of similar dimensions.

You can pry open the plastic enclosure: It is held together with some notches along the sides and a bit of (weak) glue. If your fingers and nails are nimble, you can use just them; otherwise, there are tools for these kinds of tasks (e.g. guitar picks, or "spudgers", or maybe an old credit card you're not using):

Anyway, here's what we get when we open the enclosure:

[image]

and here's what we see when you separate the HDD itself from its SATA-to-USB(+power) interface:

[image]

We are now left with a simpler problem: Recovering/accessing data on a 2.5" HDD. The drive model is: ST2000LM007.

#### 2. Try another SATA-to-USB interface

If you happen to have another SATA-to-USB adapter (e.g. [search for one on AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?SearchText=sata%20to%20usb)), try connecting the disk through it. This is not the "last resort" (e.g. these adapters aren't always 100% compatible with all drives, especially if they're a bit older), but it's worth a shot.

If the drive mounts - carefully copy all the data off of it and elsewhere; don't put a lot of trust in it. If the beeping comes from the drive - it's probably the drive that's faulty, and you should probably talk to a professional. (Or ask a followup question?)

Comment: Connect it using a different sata to usb adapter or generic enclosure (cheap on amazon), then connect to any pc, see if it will mount.

Comment: @Moab: I actually just did - but it didn't work. Will update this answer.

Comment: does it spin up or click?

Comment: @Moab: I used a plugable USB3-SATA-UASP1. The drive spun up and down and again a few times; it also beeped - at variying frequencies. As it was spinning, I thought I might have heard... I dunno, not sure, but it might have been a very fine scratching sound.

Comment: does not sound good, critical data on it with no other backups?

Comment: @Moab: No critical data, but - no other backup. Mostly video and audio files.